# Preview an image before it is saved to database in Yii using Jquery

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, yii

I am not understanding how should I carry on to Preview an image before it is
     being  saved to database in yii using jquery or any method that you can suggest

view

```
<img id="preview_image" 
src="images/<?php echo $model->pimg; ?>"  
 width="150px"      height="120px"/>

<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'pimg'); ?>
<?php echo $form->fileField($model, 'pimg',array('change'=>preview(this));); ?>

<?php echo $form->error($model,'pimg'); ?>
```

the jquery code

```
    function preview(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e) {
        $('#preview_image')
            .attr('src', e.target.result)
            .width(100)
            .height(120);
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
    }
```

Fatal error to function call preview().

How should I integrate this Jquery function in above form ....... $form has the   htmlOptions

PLEASE HELP! I am new to Yii and am loosing my mind on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This bellow code shows the image preview using jQuery

```
        var imageTypes = ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png']; //Validate the images to show
        function showImage(src, target)
        {
            var fr = new FileReader();
            fr.onload = function(e)
            {
                target.src = this.result;
            };
            fr.readAsDataURL(src.files[0]);

        }

        var uploadImage = function(obj)
        {
            var val = obj.value;
            var lastInd = val.lastIndexOf('.');
            var ext = val.slice(lastInd + 1, val.length);
            if (imageTypes.indexOf(ext) !== -1)
            {
                var id = $(obj).data('target');                    
                var src = obj;
                var target = $(id)[0];                    
                showImage(src, target);
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
```

And your HTML should be

```
        <input type="file" name="image" onchange="uploadImage(this)" data-target="#aImgShow" />
        <img id="aImgShow" src="" class="carImage" />
```

Comment: i am using yii not html therefore above html code doesn't work for yii........ and I am done ......but then thanx :)

Comment: @tisha, For your task you need the solution in client side scripting. Server side scripting wont help here.